# A concatenated dataframe in python when exported to csv shows blank rows

Tags: python, pandas

While implementing the below logistic regression for titanic data set, the rows which had no values are dropped. But these dropped rows still appear as blank rows when they are concatenated with the predictions. Why is this happening?

Please refer https://www.kaggle.com/c/titanic/data for original data.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import os
dir_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
os.chdir(dir_path)
train = pd.read_csv('titanic_train.csv')
sns.set_style('whitegrid')

#Data cleaning
train.drop('Cabin',axis=1,inplace=True)
train.dropna(inplace=True)
#Categorical data to dummy vars
sex = pd.get_dummies(train['Sex'],drop_first=True)
embark = pd.get_dummies(train['Embarked'],drop_first=True)
train.drop(['Sex','Embarked','Name','Ticket','PassengerId'],axis=1,inplace=True)
train = pd.concat([train,sex,embark],axis=1)
print(train.head())

#Develop model
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train,X_test,y_train,y_test=train_test_split(train.drop('Survived',axis=1),train['Survived'],test_size=0.3,random_state=101)
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
logmodel = LogisticRegression()
logmodel.fit(X_train,y_train)
predictions=logmodel.predict(X_test)
predser=pd.Series(predictions)
trainnew=pd.concat([X_test,y_test,predser],axis=1)
trainnew.to_csv('trainresults.csv',index=False)
```

Sample of the dataset after cleaning:

```
   Survived  Pclass   Age  SibSp  Parch     Fare  male  Q  S
0         0       3  22.0      1      0   7.2500     1  0  1
1         1       1  38.0      1      0  71.2833     0  0  0
2         1       3  26.0      0      0   7.9250     0  0  1
3         1       1  35.0      1      0  53.1000     0  0  1
4         0       3  35.0      0      0   8.0500     1  0  1
5         0       3  24.0      0      0   8.4583     1  1  0
6         0       1  54.0      0      0  51.8625     1  0  1
7         0       3   2.0      3      1  21.0750     1  0  1
8         1       3  27.0      0      2  11.1333     0  0  1
9         1       2  14.0      1      0  30.0708     0  0  0
```

The output csv looks like this

```
     Pclass    Age  SibSp  Parch      Fare  male    Q    S  Survived    SPred
0   NaN     NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN       NaN   NaN  NaN  NaN        0.0
1   NaN     NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN       NaN   NaN  NaN  NaN        0.0
2   NaN     NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN       NaN   NaN  NaN  NaN        1.0
3   NaN     NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN       NaN   NaN  NaN  NaN        1.0
4   NaN     NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN       NaN   NaN  NaN  NaN        0.0
5   NaN     NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN       NaN   NaN  NaN  NaN        0.0
6    1.0     54.00  0.0    0.0    51.8625   1.0   0.0  1.0  0.0       0.0
7    3.0     2.00   3.0    1.0    21.0750   1.0   0.0  1.0  0.0       0.0
8    3.0     27.00  0.0    2.0    11.1333   0.0   0.0  1.0  1.0       0.0
9    2.0     14.00  1.0    0.0    30.0708   0.0   0.0  0.0  1.0       1.0
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. _The output csv looks like this_ Please do not share information as images unless absolutely necessary. See: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/.

Comment: Image replaced with data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the index of `predser` is misaligned with the indices of X_test and y_test. One way to solve it to change the index before the `concat`, as in:

```
predser.index = y_test.index.  # <== new line

trainnew=pd.concat([X_test,y_test,predser],axis=1)
```

Comment: Thanks much for the fix. But I can't understand why the index of dropped rows still exists in the dataframe. Is there a way to remove them too?

Comment: Sure. To reset the index to the default integer index (0, 1, 2, etc) use df.reset_index(drop=True).

Comment: BTW - if this answers your question, do you mind accepting my answer for future generations?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am new here and TIL about accept feature